# foreach loop with conditions

Tags: c#, .net

I can do loop with more then one condition like this:

```
for (int i = 0; condition1 && condition2 && ... && conditionN  ; i++) {

}
```

Is there any way to do it using foreach:

```
foreach (var i in arr and while condition1 && condition2 && ... && conditionN) {
}
```

But without using `break;`?

I need this in order to pass on Enumerable and I don't want continue iterations if my condition is not true.

Comment: I'm surprised no one suggested you use a method for all those conditions.

Comment: @Ande Turner: Can you explain?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the [Enumerable.TakeWhile Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile.aspx):

```
foreach (var i in arr.TakeWhile(j => condition1 && ... && conditionN))
{
    // do something
}
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
foreach (var j in arr)
{
    if (!(condition1 && ... && conditionN))
    {
        break;
    }
    var i = j;
    // do something
}
```