# OR condition in foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach

The following is the syntax I'm using for a conditional foreach loop. Is it possible to have the condition include and OR statement as well? I have tried something like this:

```
(i => i.Status <condition> || x => x.IssueType <condition>)
```

however with no luck.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(i => i.Status != "C"  ))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053493/foreach-loop-with-conditions read here

Comment: my c# is a little rusty but isn't `||` the equivalent of `orelse`? does useing `|` give you what you are looking for?

Comment: do you mean: @foreach (var item in Model.Where(i => i.Status != "C" || i.IssueType == "SomeIssue" ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put your `Or` conditions in one `linq` expression

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(i => i.Status != "C" || i.IssueType <condition>))
```